# How to extract hour from query in postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have timestamp in my table and i want to extract only hour from it. I search and find a extract function but unable to use as a query. Do i need to convert first timestamp in varchar and then extract hour from it? 
Here is my query:

```
select extract(hour from timestamp '2001-02-16 20:38:40') // example
```

actual query:

```
select extract(hour from timestamp observationtime) from smartvakt_device_report
```

Comment: What is the exact type of `observationtime`?

Comment: observationtime: timestamp without time zone,

Answer (score 125, accepted):

The following should work

```
select extract(hour from observationtime) from smartvakt_device_report
```

Comment: Ahh Thanks alot :)

Comment: is there any way to get hours in **hh** format? It returns 0 instead I want it as 00

Answer (score 12):

```
SELECT to_char(now(), 'HH24:MI:SS')  hour_minute_second
```

Comment: Please add a description to your answer that exactly what your code does.

Answer (score 7):

`EXTRACT` does not work with Grafana but `date_part` does.
The solution for me was:

```
SELECT date_part('hour', observationtime::TIMESTAMP) FROM smartvakt_device_report;
```

Reference: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT

Answer (score 6):

The word `timezone` is redundant (read: wrong). You just need to give the column's name. E.g.:

```
db=> select extract(hour from observationtime) from smartvakt_device_report;

 date_part 
-----------
        19
(1 row)
```