# How can I do to get the hour from a date column with Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a date field like this `'2020-01-05 15:00:00.000000'` and I would like to get only the hour from this date field.

How can I do this?

Comment: `extract(hour from columnname)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract hour from query in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39334814/how-to-extract-hour-from-query-in-postgres)